# mistakes in prime number checker c#

Tags: c#

i've write this piece of code to check if a number is prime or not, but it doesen't work, I mean that the output is:

1 isn't a prime number

2 is a prime number

3 isn't a prime number

4 is a prime number  etc.

please can you tell me what are my mistakes,
thanks

p.s. i've write`number =1` because i can't divide a number for 0.

```
for( int number =1;number <101 && number >0;number++)
{
    int reimander = (number / 1) & (number / number);
    Console.WriteLine(number +(reimander == 0 ? " is a prime number" : " isn't a prime number"));
}
```

Comment: Well, `number / number` is always going to be 1, and `number / 1` is always going to be number. So your code is effectively: `int reimander = number & 1;`. That finds the remainder when dividing by 2, so all you're checking is whether the number is even or not.

Comment: A prime number is a number that can **only** be divided by 1 and itself. Your code checks if the number can be divided by one and itself, but fails to check if it can be divided by other numbers.

Comment: `int reimander = (number / 1) & (number / number);` this just gives you number is even or odd. it is equivalent of `number & 1`

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are two sorts of problem here: the is-prime algorithm and the C# syntax.

- To understand the algorithm for whether a number is prime, search math sites online. For example, [here](http://www.counton.org/explorer/primes/checking-if-a-number-is-prime/).
- Once you know how the math works, you can convert it into code. Based on the code you already have, you should learn [the difference between `&` and `&&`](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-and-in-C) and [how to get a remainder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator).

Comment: I'm curious about the down-votes. Certainly I'm happy to correct or remove the answer. Any suggestions on what would make it more useful? If nothing else, I'd like to make future answers better.

Comment: [This doesn't answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); it doesn't show what the OP's mistakes are and gives no guidance on how to fix them. It provides links but [links are not answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) and when they expire your answer will make no sense at all.

Comment: Right, so it turns out that "You can't delete answers that have been accepted.". (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221) So I'll just leave it as it is, and hope it doesn't get down-voted further.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [Daisy Shipton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9574109/daisy-shipton), your checkings are not sufficient to determine if your number is prime.

In order for a number to be prime, it has to be only divisible by one or itself.
That mean you should check the division by every single numbers between 3 and the number which you are checking the fact of behing prime.

In reality, you don't need to check every numbers between 3 and your number but only the ones between 3 and the square of your number.

In fact, if a whole number k is composite (non prime), it can be written as the product of two whole numbers p and q : k = p*q

Howevern those two numbers p and q can't be simultaneously greater than the square (s) of k, because in this case, their product whould be greater than k.
if p > s and q > s, then p x q > s x s, that to say p x q > k.

The code should looks like something like that (not tested) :

```
public static bool IsPrime(int number)
    {
        /****** easy check before going to long calculations *******/
        if (number < 2) return false; // A prime number is always greater than 1
        if (number == 2) return true; // 2 is prime
        if (number % 2 == 0) return false; // Even numbers except 2 are not prime

        /****** if your number is Odd and not equals to 2, 
                you have to check every numbers between 3 
                and the square of your number               *******/
        var boundary = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number)); // square of your number

        // increment i by 2 because you already checked that your number is Odd 
        // and therefore not divisible by an Even number
        for (int i = 3; i <= boundary; i += 2) 
        {
            if (number % i == 0) return false; // the number can be devided by an other => COMPOSITE number
        }
        return true; // number at least equals to 3, divisible only by one or itself => PRIME number
    }
```

Now you could do a basic loop for each numbers you want to test and call this function of them. Their is a lot of methods to calculate a series of prime numbers but their are also much more complicated to understand.

```
 for (int number = 1; number < 101 && number > 0; number++)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(number + " is " + (IsPrime(number) ? "prime" : "not prime"));
 }
```